# “There is a woman who has taken a ﬂight on every”, does the sequence of quantifiers matter here?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

“There is a woman who has taken a ﬂight on every airline in the world”, if $P(w,f)$: "w has taken a flight f", $Q(f,a)$: "f is a flight of airline a", w:all women in the world, f:all airplane flights, a:all airlines

It can be translated to $∃w∀a∃f (P (w, f ) ∧ Q(f, a))$, but I was wondering that is the sequence of ∃w∀a∃f important here? Can I rewrite it as ∃f∃w∀a, or ∃f∀a∃w,etc.?

Comment: "a ﬂight on every” A flight on every *what*?

Comment: @Did I guess  every airline

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that there are only two airlines in the world, KLM and NOP, which operate no joint flight, and only two women in the world, Anna and Zoë. Consider the following two possible states of affairs.

1. Anna has flown on KLM and on NOP, and Zoë has never flown at all.
2. Anna has flown on KLM but not on NOP, and Zoë has flown on NOP but not on KLM.

In the first scenario there is indeed a woman who has flown on every airline in the world: Anna has done so. In the second scenario there is no such woman, since each woman has flown on just one of the two airlines. Thus, the sentence

$$\exists w\,\forall a\,\exists f\,\big(P(w,f)\land Q(f,a)\big)\tag{1}$$

is true in the first scenario but not in the second.

Now let’s look at the sentence

$$\forall a\,\exists w\,\exists f\,\big(P(w,f)\land Q(f,a)\big)\;.\tag{2}$$

This says that no matter which airline I pick, there is a woman who has taken a flight on that airline. This statement is true in *both* scenarios. In the first scenario it’s true because no matter whether I consider KLM or NOP, Anna has taken a flight on that airline. In the second it’s true because if I pick KLM, I find that Anna has taken a flight on it, and if I pick NOP, I find that Zoë has done so. This shows that $(1)$ and $(2)$ cannot be equivalent: in this little universe $(2)$ is true in both scenarios, while $(1)$ is true in only one of them.

The general rule is that you can always interchange two quantifiers of the same type: you can change $\exists x\,\exists y$ to $\exists y\,\exists x$ or $\forall x\,\forall y$ to $\forall y\,\forall x$ without changing the meaning. Interchanging an existential and a universal quantifier, on the other hand, *will* change the meaning. Since the sequence of quantifiers in $(1)$, the correct translation, alternates $\exists$ and $\forall$, any interchange of quantifiers will change the meaning. This is true even if we interchange the two existential quantifiers to get

$$\exists f\,\forall a\,\exists w\,\big(P(w,f)\land Q(f,a)\big)\;.\tag{3}$$

This says that there is some flight — call it Flight $666$ — such that no matter which airline I pick there is a woman who has taken Flight $666$ **and** Flight $666$ is a flight of that airline. In particular, in our little universe this implies that Flight $666$ is operated by both KLM and NOP, which is false: KLM and NOP do not have any joint flights. Thus, $(3)$, unlike $(1)$ and $(2)$, is false in *both* of our scenarios, so it is not equivalent to either of the earlier statements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are different. In particular, in both of your rewrite suggestions, your sentence implies that there is a single flight $f$ such that for all airlines $a$, $f$ is a flight of airline $a$. Your original sentence implies no such thing.

Comment: After ∃w, how do I decide which one is next? ∀a or ∃f?

Comment: This problem makes me confused.